# use of HTTP Content-Disposition

Tags: content-disposition

I have this code:

```
resp.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
```

When the file name is `a_b_c.doc` or `abc.doc` the name of the downloaded file is displayed correctly.

However, when the file name is `a b c .doc` the name of the downloaded file is only `a`.

How can we work around this?

Answer (score 3):

Quote the filename: `"filename.doc"`.

Answer (score -1):

You always MUST quote the filename anyway. See §19.5.1 "Content-Disposition" in [RFC 2616 Section 19](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html) and $2.2 "Basic Rules" [RFC 2616 Section 2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html) which defines "quoted-string".

Comment: the relevant spec RFC 6266

Comment: @JulianReschke Isn't RFC 6266 just an "Update" which extends the spec to be applicable to HTTP/1.1 - but does not invalidate RFC 2616?  (IMO, 2616 is till valid).

Comment: No, it replaces what RFC 2616 had to say about Content-Disposition.

Comment: @JulianReschke OK, so in the OP's case above, and according RFC 6266 (June 2011), argument `fileName` must be a `quoted-string` OR a `token`. In RFC 2616 only `quoted-string` was allowed. There are a few more changes in RFC 6266. Thanks for the clarification! It seems difficult to track all the changes, though :/